# How to replace string with quotes and brackets in file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

How I can replace string which contains quotes and brackets in a file using powershell ?

I have file with settings c:\app\settings.js

```
app_set("safe.mode", true);
app_set("api.uri", "https://apiurl.com");
app_set("api.version", 1);
```

And script ChangeSettins.ps1 but it actually doesn't change strings in a file.

```
$SettingsFile = c:\app\settings.js

$SAFEMODE = 'app_set("safe.mode", true);'
$APIURI = 'app_set("api.uri", "https://apiurl.com");'
$APIVERSION = 'app_set("api.version", 1);'

$SAFEMODE_PROFILE = Get-Content $SettingsFile | Select-String -Pattern "safe.mode"
#$SAFEMODE_PROFILE

$APIURI_PROFILE = Get-Content $SettingsFile | Select-String -Pattern "api.uri"
#$APIURI_PROFILE

$APIVERSION_PROFILE = Get-Content $SettingsFile | Select-String -Pattern "api.version"
#$APIVERSION_PROFILE

If ("$SAFEMODE_PROFILE" -eq "$SAFEMODE") {   
    Write-Host "safe mode is enabled"

}  

Else {
    Write-Host "enabling safe mode"
    (Get-Content $SettingsFile) | Foreach-Object { $_ -Replace "$SAFEMODE_PROFILE", "$SAFEMODE" } | Set-Content $SettingsFile

} 

If ("$APIURI_PROFILE" -eq "$APIURI") {   
    Write-Host "uri is correct"

}  

Else {
    Write-Host "updating uri"
    (Get-Content $SettingsFile) | Foreach-Object { $_ -Replace "$APIURI_PROFILE", "$APIURI" } | Set-Content $SettingsFile

} 

If ("$APIVERSION_PROFILE" -eq "$APIVERSION") {  
    Write-Host "api version is 1"

}

Else {
    Write-Host "changing api version to 1"
    (Get-Content $SettingsFile) | Foreach-Object { $_ -Replace "$APIVERSION_PROFILE", "$APIVERSION" } | Set-Content $SettingsFile
}
```

Comment: Use string termination in your remove/replace efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Replacement Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#replacement-operator)

> The `-replace` operator replaces all or part of a value with the
>   specified value using **regular expressions**.

Apply the [Regex.Escape(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netcore-3.1) where necessary, e.g. as follows:

```
$_ -Replace [regex]::Escape("$APIURI_PROFILE"), "$APIURI"
```